# Centering footer nav links horizontally

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason I am unable to center my footer links horizontally. I want my links to be centered, then the "All Rights Reserved" section underneath that centered as well. I am able to center the "All Rights Reserved" by applying .center to it but it doesn't affect the list items. Any idea what I am missing or doing wrong?

Here is my footer partial from my Ruby on Rails app, I am using Bootstrap 3.0 for styling.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <div class="container center">
        <ul class="nav">
            <li class="navbar-text"><%= link_to "About", about_path %></li>
            <li class="navbar-text"><%= link_to "FAQs", faq_path %></li>
            <li class="navbar-text"><%= link_to "Contact Us", contact_path %></li>
            <li class="navbar-text"><%= link_to "Terms of Use & Privacy Policy", privacy_path %></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="container center">
        <p>Company 2013. All Rights Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</nav>
```

The .center is just:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
 }
```

I tried applying the techniques used from this question: [Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-div-using-bootstrap-3-markup-or-css) without any luck in this situation(Although this actually helped me resolve another problem I was having)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/k4Njb/ ?

Comment: Hey ajc, I actually want the list items horizontal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the below css

```
.navbar ul li{
    display:inline-block;
 }
```

As Zachary said you can add `margin: 0 auto;` to make your ul element centered to page/parent element

Comment: I can't seem to get either of these to work... Maybe I am doing something wrong.

Comment: May be other attributes for the parent elements are effecting your code. I suggest you to use Firebug addon in Firefox to identify what other element attributes are effectively applying your footer. I'm sure that it will definitely helps you in identifying the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your li elements are set to inline-block and are already listed horizontally, try centering your ul tag with the following CSS:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```