# How to center form in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

How can I center my login form ? I'm using bootstrap column but it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-6">
            <h2>Log in</h2>   
            <div>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2</td>
                        <td>2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>3</td>
                        <td>3</td>
                    </tr>
                 </table>
             </div> 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-div-using-bootstrap-3-markup-or-css

Answer (score 62, accepted):

A simple way is to add

```
.center_div{
    margin: 0 auto;
    width:80% /* value of your choice which suits your alignment */
}
```

to you class `.container`.Add `width:xx %` to it and you get perfectly centered div!

eg :

```
<div class="container center_div">
```

but i feel that by default `container` is centered in BS!

Answer (score 223):

There is a simple way of doing this in Bootstrap. Whenever I need to make a `div` center in a page, I divide all columns by 3 (total Bootstrap columns = 12, divided by 3 >>> 12/3 = 4). Dividing by four gives me three columns. Then I put my `div` in middle column. And all this math is performed by this way:

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">my div here</div>
```

`col-md-4` makes one column of 4 Bootstrap columns. Let's say it's the main column. `col-md-offset-4` adds one column (of width of 4 Bootstrap column) to both sides of the main column.

Comment: This is clearly the correct answer, and is even done in a "bootstrap-ish" way.

Comment: agreed with you @Donato,  years gap may be kept it from getting marked!!

Comment: It does not work when the element to align is longer than the width of the actual width of centered `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">`. But I just decrease the offset and it does the work, thanks.

Comment: Note that you have to add one div above and one after the deiv you are working on

Comment: This solution is not very good because it makes your div take up 4 columns which won't look good in some screen sizes. When you have a mostly empty page with a centered form in the exact middle, it is best to have set a width to the div.

Comment: This does not look right to me: the text is not centered properly, but only using a horizontal offset such that it is placed left-aligned in a centered column

Comment: yes, it doesn't center the text, it makes center the div. Use text-center class in this div to make the text centered.

Answer (score 8):

The total columns in a row has to add up to 12. So you can do col-md-4 col-md-offset-4. So your breaking up your columns into 3 groups of 4 columns each. Right now you have a 4 column form with an offset by 6 so you are only getting 2 columns to the right side of your form. You can also do col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 which would give you a 8 column form with 2 columns each of space left and right or col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 (6 column form with 3 columns space on each side), etc.

Answer (score 6):

I tried this and it worked

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 col-md-offset-5 align-center ">
       <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" >
  </div>
 </div> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

I Guess you are trying to center the form both horizontally and vertically with respect to the any container div.

You don't have to make use of bootstrap for it. Just use the popular method (below) to center the form.

```
.container{
 position relative;
}
.form{
 position: absolute;
 top: 50%;
 left: 50%;
 transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: got it working without . before form (so: form { // etct}

Answer (score 4):

use centered class with offset-6 like below sample.

```
<body class="container">
<div class="col-lg-1 col-offset-6 centered">
    <img data-src="holder.js/100x100" alt="" />
</div>
```

Comment: Where does this `centered` class come from? My copy of Bootstrap 3 does not contain such a class

Answer (score 1):

Wrap whatever you are trying to center around this div.

```
<div class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle"></div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/

Comment: This worked form me

Answer (score 0):

Many people advise using `col-` and `col-offset-` classes, but it doesn't work right for me, it centers the form only for a certain screen size, but if you change it, the markup slides out.

I found two ways to align form:

Use a custom CSS:

```
<div class=".center">
  <form>

  </form>
</div>

.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
form {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 500px; /*find your value*/
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Original code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38838297/how-to-center-form-data-using-bootstrap)

OR just copy a CSS class "**justify-content-center**" from bootstrap 4, it's very short:

```
.justify-content-center {
    -ms-flex-pack: center !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
}
```

And then use it:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-inline justify-content-center">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you insist on using Bootstrap, use `d-inline-block` like below

```
    <div class="row d-inline-block">
       <form class="form-inline">
         <div class="form-group d-inline-block">
           <input type="email" aria-expanded="false" class="form-control mr-2" 
               placeholder="Enter your email">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">submit</button>
         </div>
       </form>
     </div>
```

Answer (score -3):

```
<div class="col-md-4 offset-md-4"> 
put your form here
</div>
```

Comment: The provided answer was flagged for review as a Low Quality Post.  Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation.

Comment: @Rob While it was flagged as low quality, low quality is reserved for answers that are a problem requiring immediate attention, as per the instructions from a moderator.  It’s frowned upon to leave code only answers, hence the comment.  However, this wouldn’t be removed for being low quality, or even wrong, based upon my experience with declined low quality flags.  Additionally, it wouldn’t be removed for being short and it doesn’t fall under under other flags, so it was marked ok.  The system doesn’t allow for removing short answers, but they can be downvoted.