# Bootstrap 3 center container div

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

I can't seem to find the way to center a container that has a couple of images and a label.  Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">  
       <div class="col-sm-1" style="width:88px;padding-left:0px">
           <img id="Img1" runat="server" src="images/image1.gif" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:60px">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12 BaseColor1" style="text-align:center">
                   <img id="Img2" runat="server" src="images/image2.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row" style="background-color:white;color: black;text-align:center">
                  <div class="col-sm-12" style="vertical-align:central">
                       <asp:Label Runat="server" Height="26px" ID="lblComp">COMPANY</asp:Label>
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

How do I make the entire container div or the "row" div (below) to center in the browser?

Comment: have you tried adding text-align: center; to your row class?

Comment: Yes. I tried to add the style with text-align: center  to the row div but it made no difference. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: how bout your container class?

Comment: @briskovich  Tried that too; to no avail.

Comment: add the class col-sm-offset-2 to the first div inside your first row

Comment: @JuanC.  This does the job. Thank you.! But I don't understand how it works. If you can, please explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "margin:0 auto"

```
<div class="container" style="margin:0 auto">
   <div class="row">  
       <div class="col-sm-1" style="width:88px;padding-left:0px">
           <img id="Img1" runat="server" src="images/image1.gif" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-sm-8" style="height:60px">
           <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm-12 BaseColor1" style="text-align:center">
                   <img id="Img2" runat="server" src="images/image2.gif" />
                </div>
            </div>
             <div class="row" style="background-color:white;color: black;text-align:center">
                  <div class="col-sm-12" style="vertical-align:central">
                       <asp:Label Runat="server" Height="26px" ID="lblComp">COMPANY</asp:Label>
                   </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

You can also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-div-using-bootstrap-3-markup-or-css?rq=1) about using Bootstrap's "offsets"

Comment: maccettura.  Thank you for the suggestion. It does not work but I am reading the suggested post. The suggestion of JuanC does the job.