# How can I center an column on bootstrap when it is an uneven number

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following scenario:

I have a `<div class="row">` and then I have another `<div class="col-lg-3">` where I will be putting the picture of a profile of an user. The problem is that I would like to center that picture to be in the middle of the available space, so I would normally do this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-x">
        <img src="..." class="..." alt="..." title="..." data-size="...">
    </div>
</div>
```

What would be the x value on the class of the `<div class="col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-x">` If I wanted to center that `div`? Anybody has any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duplicate of [Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-div-using-bootstrap-3-markup-or-css?rq=1)

"You can center any column size by using the proven margin: 0 auto; technique, you just need to take care of the floating that is added by Bootstrap's grid system. I recommend defining a custom CSS class like the following:

```
.col-centered{
    float: none;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Now you can add it to any column size at any screen size and it will work seamlessly with Bootstrap's responsive layout :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered"></div>
</div>
```

Note: With both techniques you could skip the .row element and have the column centered inside a .container but you would notice a minimal difference in the actual column size because of the padding in the container class."

Comment: Did work, had to add some extra css for the img class and other things, but the basic idea was correct. Thanks a lot.