# Bootstrap 3 - aligning vertical and horizontal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have been looking over other questions posted on SO and tried the CSS however I cannot seem to align the "box" HxV within the container.

What is the best way to get it to display HxV responsive?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 center-block"> 
                box
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Align it how?  Centered completely?  Check here http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/

Comment: @Deryck Thanks but I am wanting it to be center of the browser window etc

Comment: centered like a modal (fixed position, no scrolling) or centered just...centered

Comment: @Deryck Fixed centered no scrolling

Comment: OK well first try this: instead of `col-md-offset-2` use `col-md-offset-1` or `col-md-offset-3` and you can remove that `center-block` since the offset and column size will determine its placement

Comment: If that doesn't work, see [this past answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-div-using-bootstrap-3-markup-or-css) and worst-case, [this is beautiful](http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an class like `.centred-col` and write an rule like

`.centred-col{  float: none; margin:auto;}`add this after ur .col classes.

Answer (score 0):

Using .container centers and auto margins your grid to begin with, there should be no need for offsets:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12"> 
            box
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: .col-xs-12 will set your column to the full width after container margins from the XS size to the LG size.

Documentation: [Bootstrap CSS Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/) under "Containers".