# How to make the child div to traverse almost the entire width of the parent div using bootstrap css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my UI, I have an outer div, which has two rows of child divs . It works fine, but the problem is that there is a lot of gap on either side of the first child div and similarly too much gap between the two child divs in the second row. Is there a way to minimize the gap on either side of the first child div and make as close to the size of the parent div and also minimize the gap between the divs in the second row?

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" >
   <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px">
        <!-- This is what is being used to set the child panels -->
        <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-11" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
            <div class="traverse-plugins"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-top:20px">
        <div class="col-sm-11 col-md-11" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto; ">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5" style="float:left">
                <div class="left-plugins"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-5" style="float: right">
                <div class="right-plugins"></div>
            </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I'd do a `col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1` to center it. LOVE foundation for this reason...they have centering built in so you can do 11. The additional solution here will also work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18153551/3739498

Comment: Please add your code. It is much easier to read the code itself than to try to understand a written description of it.