# Bootstrap: Centering col-md-5?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-5

I feel like this is a very weird question but I couldn't seem to find a solution online.

If I have a `col-md-5`, I can't seem to center it.
As far as I understood the grid system, if I choose a column size (1-12), in order to control the position of the column I use col-##-offset-#.

So if I have a `col-md-4`, I would use `col-md-offset-4` to push it 4 columns from the left, and then it will be centered. The idea is that, to center a column, there must be the same amount of columns within the grid from the left of it and from the right of it.

Now, what if I have a, let's say, `col-md-5`? How can I center it?
Doing something like `col-md-4` will leave 3 from the right. I tried several things but no success.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 23):

**Bootstrap 5**

In Bootstrap 5 (and Bootstrap 4) this can be done simply with `mx-auto` for auto left/right margins...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
     <div class="col-sm-5 mx-auto">
        Centered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This works in Bootstrap 5 as well.

Answer (score 8):

```
<div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Smartest answer! if you want to do something like `col-*-3` centered, you can't because you don't have `col-*-offset-4.5` but you could use `col-*-4` and `col-*-offset-4`. Yes, it could be so big for your proposes but the hack is to add an inner div specifying other size and offset to center it. e.g `col-*-8` and `col-*-offset-2`. The result is something shorter than parent div specified but bigger than just applyed `col-*-2` and `col-*-offset-5` to the parent. It should be the acepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Twitter bootstrap applies `float` property on columns `col-*-#`. First, we need to override that by re-setting `float` to `none` for a specific column.

Then we can give the column a `margin-left`/`right` of `auto` to align it to center horizontally — **[Example Here](http://jsbin.com/noquqi/3)**.

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .col-md-center {
    float: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-center">
    <!--                 ^-- Added class name
     --> ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is an easier way to do this that utilizes the existing bootstrap classes.  Please see my answer.

Comment: @Ryan Friedman Your method isn't the best, because you are creating a parent div to get what you wanted, instead this method, which I really think is the best one in my opinion

Comment: It's better to use built in Bootstrap classes that account for responsiveness then create a new CSS class with a media query, and add.   It is the best solution offered on this page and there's nothing inherently wrong with a parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet is to make your own rule for this, create a 4.5 offset.

left margin = (100/12) * (12-5) / 2 = 29.175%

```css
.col-xs-5 {
  background-color: red;
}
.col-xs-offset-4_5 {
  margin-left: 29.175%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-4_5">.col-xs-5</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or you could go this way, utilize a 6 column, but remove 1 column by adding halv a column padding on each side.

```css
.col-xs-6.morepadding {
  padding: 0px 4.16%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 morepadding">.col-xs-6 with half the width of a column as padding on each side</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is an easier way to do this that utilizes the existing bootstrap classes.  Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post and the top answer:
[Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Specifically "Approach #2", I think is what you are looking for

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/85oy836u/1/

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-5" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto; background: green;">col-xs-5</div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like Hashem beat me to the answer :)

Answer (score -2):

Well you can try this

```
.col-centered {
display:inline-block;
float:none;
}
```

And here is the `html` for that

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-centered"></div>
</div>
```

Thats just general idea of it but here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/bhavuksuthar/15zabwg4/) i found online.

Answer (score -3):

Try adding class `text-center` like this:

```
 <div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12 text-center">
BLABLA
</div>
</div>
```

This solution works with col-md-5 too

Comment: I Just suggested a solution. If not worked for you , sorry, but downvoted my answer is unnecessary.

Comment: sorry for down voting but text-center will center the text nothing else