# Center a column in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have 2 columns in a bootstrap page like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

What I want to center is the right column (the second one). When I reduce the screen size to simulate smartphone devices I see the column aligned to the left side. What I want is to center all the content in that column either in small devices or big devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`offset`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) classes provided by `Bootstrap`:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-8 col-md-offset-0">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Left column</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <h2>Right column</h2>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation:**

First of all in your second column when you use col-xs-6 and do not specify col-sm-* it means that this is also col-sm-6:

```
<div class="col-xs-6"></div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6"></div>
```

This two lines of code are the same (it is better to use first one). The same goes for offset classes (if you specify `col-xs-offset-3` and do not specify col-sm-offset-* it means that this is also `col-sm-offset-3`).

In bootstrap you have 12 columns. If you want to center `col-sm-6` you have to offset this by 3 columns (`col-sm-offset-3` **3**+6+3).

I had to specify offsets to 0 in **md** columns because I had to overwrite `col-sm-offset-3`. If I would not done that, it would have been `col-md-offset-3`.

### [CODEPEN EXAMPLE](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwzJyN)

Comment: Yes, but in this case what offset class should I use to do this?

Comment: With your code the second column is displayed under the first column in big screen size. I want the two columns display in the same row. Now when the screen size is reduced I see the content centered but not in full size mode

Comment: Updated, I think this is what you want, check the example.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I'm talking about. Just what I need. Clean and simple. Maybe I have to learn how to use correctly the offset classes. Why do you use exactly those offsets?

Answer (score 1):

I would utilise Bootstrap class "center-block" in this case.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8"></div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="center-block"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example:
http://www.bootply.com/fWjX4eLAuR

P.S don't use "container" class inside the rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand what you want, because it is pretty simple.

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="text-center">My text is centered even in a small device</p>
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

and if you want to add a virtual margin :

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-8">
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-offset-3 col-md-4 col-md-offset-3">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <p class="text-center">My text is centered even in a small device</p>
      </div>
   <div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will put a carousel of images inside the fluid container

Comment: Ok so I think that this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3?rq=1) will help you.