# Center a Bootstrap Container

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, containers, center

While building a webpage with Bootstrap so far, the `navbar` looks great! While working with content, I added all CDN links in the header and added the `.container` class in the body.

But the div seems floating to the left. I have tried to set the container to:

```
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
display: block;
class{text-align: center}
```

and many others....

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you show us the html and exact css you are using?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: well said @Paulie_D, this is important to keep in mind how to ask a question in such a place.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Center Div in Bootstrap</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="linkToCSS" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="part " style="float: none; margin: auto;">
                        //your content goes here
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add flexbox to your bootstrap container. You don't need to write any extra CSS for bootstrap if you will use pre-written bootstrap classes. As below;

```
<div class="container d-flex justify-content-center">...</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div align="center">
  Your body...
</div>
```