# .center-block with centered DIV in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to have troubles centring my div and `center-block` doesn't seem to work.
I intend to center the nested div containing the `<p>` tag. I am not so much trying to center the content inside the div. As such I would like have the center peroperty apply to the div itself rather than its contents.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 center-block">
            <h1>{{secretDisplay.secretTitle}}</h1>
                <div class="row center-block" style="text-align:left">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 center-block" style="text-align:left">
                        <p contenteditable="true" class="chat_window">
                            <img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/><img src="{% static 'img/Test1.jpg'%}" class="icon_one"/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p contenteditable="true" class="write_window">This is the test</p>
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.center-block {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

The page must be mobile responsive so Bootstrap's offset might cause issues.

Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Mike

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: Have you tried `col-md-push-*` where `*` is the number of the block.

Comment: @MNedelko, have you tried to use class `text-center` instead `center-block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot center a `col-xs-12`. It is near-100% of the available width, plus some margins. It simply has nowhere to go. If you want the contents of center-block to appear centered, which is what I'm assuming, do this:

```
.center-block {
   text-align: center;
}
```

And you might also want to remove this class from the row.

Comment: Bootstrap actually already has a class of its own: `.text-center` - see [Bootstrap Type Alignment](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment)

Comment: Hi Rando. Thank you for this. I would like the center property to apply to the div rather than the content inside the div. Will edit the question accordingly. Apology.

Comment: You cannot center a `col-xs-12`. It is near-100% of the available width, plus some margins. It simply has nowhere to go.

Comment: Ah! Thats were my error is! Thank you. However, when I change the col-xs-12 to say 3, it doesn't scale for mobile views anymore.