# "Pull center" in Bootstrap: A -D- B -E- C columns collapsing to A-B-C // D-E, how to get B between D and E?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm **not** asking for simple center aligning of columns in bootstrap. That's easy and [has been covered already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3), those solutions don't apply to what I'm trying to do here.

---

What I want, is a layout that is five column on wide devices, 2 - 3 - 2 - 3 - 2,
 collapsing down to have the three 2 columns 4 - 4 - 4, then the two 3 columns 6 - 6.

Something like this:

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 pull-left">
    A
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 pull-center">
    <!-- of course, pull-center doesn't exist, it's here to illustrate intention -->
    B
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 pull-right">
    C
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
    D
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3"> 
    E
    </div>
  </div>
```

Which, if `pull-center` existed and `float: middle` existed, would look like this on a wide device:

```
 A- _D_ B- _E_ C-
```

...and like this on a narrow device:

```
 -A-- -B-- -C--
 __D___ __E___
```

...but, because there's no such thing as `pull-center` or `float: middle;`, currently looks like this:

```
 A- B- _D_ _E_ C-
```

How can I get my `B` column to float between the two columns below it in the HTML? I've tried adding various `pull-` classes and `float` CSS to the D and E columns but can't find anything that helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think here is you want:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
    A
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-3">
    B
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-6">
    C
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-4">
    D
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-2">
    E
    </div>
</div>
```

I Use [Bootstrap column ordering](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering) .

It can easily change the order of responsive columns.

Hope it helps.

For explanation :

(Original order)

[image]

(New order)

[image]

push-* (move right * steps)

pull-* (move left * steps)

B => from (3) to (6) => push 3 steps

C => from (5) to (11) => push 6 steps

D => from (7) to (3) => pull 4 steps

E => from (10) to (8) => pull 2 steps

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I completely missed the introduction of that feature, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using float, you can make use of `.col-*-push-*` and `.col-*-pull-*` Bootstrap modifier classes to change the position of the elements.

You will end up with something like the following:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2">
    A
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-3">
    B
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-2 col-md-push-6">
    C
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-4"> 
    D
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-2"> 
    E
    </div>
  </div>
```

See [example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwJXWO).