# Bootstrap: Layout not responsive even while using correct classes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive

I think I'm using the correct Bootstrap structure, classes, etc.. So why does the layout get totally messed up when I resize the browser? What am I doing wrong?

Here's the [full code.](http://codepen.io/TheSamehMagdy/pen/PzyvQB)

```
body {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
h2 {
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
h3 {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1056px;
}
p {
    font-size: 14px;
}
nav.navbar {
    padding: 12px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    background: none;
}
nav.navbar li {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
nav.navbar li a {
     padding: 8px 20px; 
     margin-top: 0.5em;
     border-radius: 4px;
}
nav.navbar li a:link {
    color: #9faeaf;
}
nav.navbar li a.active:link,
nav.navbar li a.active:visited {
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: You'll have to show the HTML too.

Comment: perhaps you've overrides lots of css

Comment: @Juhana it's all in the codepen link.

Comment: @jonju But I have to, to customize the site and design the layout.

Comment: Yes. but you've to do it with care. It's very sensitive..

Comment: Questions have to be self-contained. Please add the HTML to the question too.

Comment: @Juhana It won't let me. Says the question is mostly code.

Comment: @Sam, go through the CSS and HTML and only keep the [bare minimum code required for someone else to replicate the issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You will then be able to post both your HTML and CSS code parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary reason your layout is not responsive is because you've set explicit height rules in your CSS. Take `section#about`, for example—if you remove the explicit `height: 980px;` you set in your stylesheet, the **Pixel Perfect** paragraph will no longer overlap with the **Looking for the perfect template to use?** title.

Second, you are improperly using the Bootstrap grid. I noticed that you have a `.container` class for almost every section. Ideally, you should remove those and only have **one** `.container` class which encapsulates the entire page (unless you want to use different container sizes on one page).

Here is an example:

```html
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <section id="intro" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div><!-- end .col-md-4 -->

            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div><!-- end .col-md-4 -->

            <div class="col-md-4">
            </div><!-- end .col-md-4 -->
        </section><!-- end #intro section -->

        <section id="about" class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div><!-- end .col-md-6 -->

            <div class="col-md-6">
            </div><!-- end .col-md-6 -->
        </section><!-- end #about section -->
    </div><!-- end .container -->
</body>
```

> **Note**: There is an exception with the Navbar/Footer, in which case you can put separate containers *inside* those elements as you already
>   did with the Navbar.

Third, use more `.row` classes as "blocks" for each vertical section on your page. You did this within your sections, but it might be a good idea to make the sections themselves individual rows as well by giving them the `.row` class—after you've removed the containers from each section.

Next, you don't *need* to define rules for every screen size as **kosmastsk** suggested. If you like the way it looks with just defining breakpoints for `col-sm` then that is up to you. It will look better, though, if you develop [mobile first](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/mobile-first-with-bootstrap-3--net-34808) and work your way up to larger screen sizes.

Also consider using more CSS [Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to help you better customize your site if you *must* override heights, widths, etc.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. btw I did wrap a single container around everything at first but then I couldn't do the full-width backgrounds. Is there a way to work around that?

Comment: In that case, wrap everything in a `.container-fluid` class and override Bootstrap's CSS to remove the padding from `.container-fluid` so everything will take up the full-width of the viewport. After that, you could have full-width backgrounds but your content (text) would be full-width as well. To get around that, I would use bootstrap columns to act as smaller containers (e.g. `.col-xs-10`) and [center that column](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18153551/5228504). That way, you would still be able to use `.row` and more column classes within it as you would in a regular `.container` class.

Answer (score 0):

In your html code, you have only used col-sm-*. So, the browser uses your structure for the .sm, .md and .lg classes but does not know what to do for the .xs class (<768 px). So, try defining the xs class first.
For example, use that code for every div

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"> ... </div>
```

Comment: Still totally messed up.

Comment: [check this out](http://codepen.io/kosmastsk/pen/OXBYqA)
Isn't it better? I would advice you to start developing with the .xs class first. Bootstrap makes it easier for you this way