# Centering a Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a Bootstrap Carousel in my home page, after some text information. I do not want a big Carousel in my page, so I decreased the size using `<div class="col-sm-6">`.
But my Carousel is positioned on the left side of the page and I was not able to center it. I would like to have it in the center of my page.
The code that I used was:

```
<div class="container">
<h4 class="text-justify">text here </h4>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
        <!-- Indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
          <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        </ol>

        <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
        <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
          <div class="item active"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/xx.JPG" alt=""></div>
          <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/xxxx.JPG" alt=""></div>
          </div>

        <!-- Left and right controls -->
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>    
        </div></div></div>
```

My CSS code was

```
.carousel-inner > .item > img,
.carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 100%;
      margin: auto;
          }
```

How can I change the position?

Comment: have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you have to place your col-sm-6 inside a row, then you can simply add a class "col-centered" and add the following CSS

```
.col-centered{
   float: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Your final code will be like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <h4 class="text-justify">text here </h4>
</div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-sm-6 col-centered">
  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
      <div class="item active"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/xx.JPG" alt=""></div>
      <div class="item"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/xxxx.JPG" alt=""></div>
      </div>

    <!-- Left and right controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Previous</span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
      <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply this style. This below code will work.

```
<div class="col-sm-6" style="
    margin: 0 auto;
    float: none;">
```