# Bootstrap 4 row does not align to middle

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to get the **content** in `<div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">` in the middle to align to middle, but to no avail. 
I know that setting the columns to a size of 2 will not fill the space of the grid system of 12 columns, but I want it to be aligned to the middle regardless.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="content-header">Header</h1>
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
               content
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
             content
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: maybe this help u.. set to that row div `display: block;` and `margin: 0 auto;`

Comment: tried it, still not working @LiborZahrádka

Comment: I am not sure what you your question is, but I think `text-align:center;` will set your text in the center of your div.

Comment: @M.Arendsen Im looking to get my content aligned to the middle, yes text-xs-center will only set text to middle, but even with align: middle doesnt get my content center in the page hmmmm

Comment: @Programmer are you trying to get the text in the center, or are you trying to get the div in the center?

Comment: the div into middle @M.Arendsen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a css trick that works

```
.row-centered {
    text-align: center;
}

.col-centered {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none;
    /* reset the text-align */
    text-align: left;
    /* inline-block space fix */
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4, like [Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3), uses `offset` to move or center entire columns. So in your case use `offset-*-4` to move it over 4 cols in the 12 col grid.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 text-xs-center">
            <h1 class="content-header">Header</h1>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2 offset-md-4 offset-lg-4">
                    content
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2">
                    content
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

To center inline elements (like text), use:
`text-center` (this was `text-center` in 3.x)

To center block elements (like DIV) or columns, use:
`mx-auto` (this was `center-block` in 3.x)

Demo: http://www.codeply.com/go/Wxzbd3a6og

There are also new [responsive alignment classes](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/utilities/#text-alignment) in Bootstrap 4 so you can align differently at various breakpoints.

Comment: this doesnt works well for me, i've dynamic content, which means there's unknown <div class="col-md-2 col-lg-2"> content </div>

Comment: Then you can use `mx-auto` on the column(s)