# How to align a <div> / <input> / <img> in center of the page, without using any CSS position property?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Is there any other short and fast way to align to your `<div>` or `<input>` or anything? Suppose I want to make a bootstrap modal:

```html
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<li>
    <button type="button" class="fa fa-search fa-2x search-icon" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#search"></button>
</li>
  
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="search" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
 <div class="modal-dialog search">
       <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
         <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      <input class="searchArea" type="search" placeholder="Search Here">
       </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If I make a modal and want to add `<input type="search">` in the modal, and without any CSS positioning (top left right bottom), can I put the INPUT SEARCH box in the center of the page?

Comment: Have you tried `text-align:center;` on a parent element of the elements you want centered?

Comment: Or in html `align="center"` though, u have to do it for every element

Comment: @RaisingAgent That is dropped in HTML5 so not recommended to start using

Answer (score 0):

Use `auto` margins for left and right. For example:

```
.searchArea {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  /* or, for example, margin: 20px auto; */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like [Bootstrap's `text-center` class](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#type-alignment) does the job:

```
<div class="text-center">
    <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <input class="searchArea" type="search" placeholder="Search Here">
</div>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/addvs3yp/)

Answer (score -2):

you could use

```
<center></center>
```

... but is deprecated

another way is using class of bootstrap

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5"></div>
</div>
```

thanks to TylerH in her answer... https://stackoverflow.com/a/18153551/4102927

but this is css in background