# center item within viewport rather than containing bootstrap column

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

[image: Screenshot that illustrates my problem]

I am trying to center an item within the viewport rather than the containing bootstrap column. The paragraph shown in the picture is within a bootstrap column with a `.col-md-4` class assigned to it. When I hover over each picture, I want the paragraph underneath to be center within the viewport. Instead, it appears as though the paragraph is left aligned within the bootstrap column. Below is the current CSS I have for the paragraph and I included a link above to better illustrate the problem.

```
.TestimonyParagraph{
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    position: relative;
    width: 50vw;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 15px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #898989;
    display: none;
}

.home-features__box:hover + .TestimonyParagraph{
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You have set the `width:50vw` what will show the content in the half of the current viewport. Have you tried changing this value?

Comment: Post all the related code

Answer (score 1):

You can use the

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

in a traditional way.
You can user flex box otherwise:-

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
```

Provide the structure of your code for better answers

Comment: I tried both and it still trying to align within the bootstrap column.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the code snippet feature to recognize the bootstrap CDN or I would post it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a

```
margin:0 auto;
```

to TestimonyParagraph? Also check here:
[Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3)

If not, please post a Jsfiddle or Codepen of your structure so we can assist better.

Comment: Yes I did try that. I added a code snippet here on stackoverflow but it isn't pulling in bootstrap properly

Answer (score 0):

Since you have set `width: 50vw;` for this element, you can simply use `left: 25vw;` (25 left + 50 for the div + 25 to the right are 100vw - full width, therefore a way to center it).

However, if the parent element doesn't span the full width (which seems to be the case in your picture), it's better do the same with percent : `left: 25%` and `width: 50%`.

Comment: I have tried that as well. The problem is that when I use width: 50% it is 50% of the parent element (which is the width of one of those pictures above). I need the Testimony paragraph to stay within it's parent div but find a way to ignore the width of it's parent.