# Placing elements center in bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to css and bootstrap and I'm trying to place an div content on center of my screen.

Currently I'm planning to do so:

```
 <div className="container">
    <div className="row">
        <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
        <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4">
            Center content here
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I could able to guess that column's are splitted into `12`. So I'm just splitting up them by `4` for `3` div's.

I just want to understand whether we can get rid of two `div`'s which just used for calculation purpose here:

```
<div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
<div className="col-sm-4 col-md-4"></div>
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: are you using bootstrap 3 or 4?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3

Comment: I'm using 3 version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use offsetting for this (see the [`col-x-offset-x` utility classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting)):

```html
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
    <div className="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
      Center content here
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @George: Thanks, I guess I'm not getting it quite right (even though it works perfectly fine). The columns are split into `12`. So if I give `col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4` what does that mean? Move only the given `div` by offset `4`? So what about remaining `4` cols? To be frank the documentation text is confusing "For example, .col-md-offset-4 moves .col-md-4 over four columns."

Comment: @batman Because there are 12 columns in a bootstrap layout, and 12 divided by 3 is 4, "offsetting" the column by 4 columns places the 4-column wide div in the middle.

Answer (score -1):

You can use native bootstrap classes that are available, for example:

```
class="text-center"

class="pagination-centered"
```