# How to Align a div in Center When Contents added Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please have a look at this Image. [image]

Here I was use the Bootstrap for aligning the divs. And created only one div. The Contents are added in this div dynamically from the admin side. then it will loop the div. That's Working fine.

But here you can see only 6 Contents are available. So 2 Divs are aligned in the left. I need these div should align in the middle of the Page. If the Contents are 7 or 5 the Second row Contents should be in the Middle. How to align these Divs Middle. Please Help me to Solve this Problem.

Here Is My Code..

`<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
        <div class="service-item hvr-grow wow fadeIn" data-wow-duration="500" data-wow-delay="100ms">
            <img src="{{ 'assets/img/icon-services.png' |theme }} ">
                <h4>{{ service['name'] }}</h4>
                <p>{{ str_limit(service['description'], 100) }}</p>
                <a href="{{ url('services') }}/{{ service['slug'] }}" class="read-more">Read More</a>
        </div>
    </div>`

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: can you please add what you have tried till now

Comment: can you show the code you have worked on so far

Comment: @Geeky, Please have a look. Code is added.

Comment: @BalaAbhinav Please have a look. Code is added.

Comment: @MelbinMathai Have a look into this http://www.minimit.com/demos/bootstrap-3-responsive-centered-columns   Or else you need to remove float:left from col-*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `display: inline` to child div and `text-align: center` to the parent div. Don't use `col-md` of bootstrap because it have `float: left` propertive

```css
.parent {
  text-align: center;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 24%;
  border: solid 1px #123;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 auto !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="parent">
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great Work. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bootstrap to set an offset for each div dynamically depending on your div's desired position or set the margin of the divs to auto. See [this](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3&ved=0ahUKEwje-L6tsvbUAhULYo8KHXttC48QFgghMAA&usg=AFQjCNHRG4l5BPq0G3Ad99LLXZjq2fTVoQ) post for a detailed explanation.