# Cannot center text of links

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have tried everything to center the text of the links I created. I am using bootstrap for some classes. For some reason I cannot use text-align: center on any of the elements to center the text.

```css
.categories_col {
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.categories_col .row {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.categories_col a {
  font-family: rockwell;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #8d8d8d;
}

.categories_col a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #087abf;
}

.categories_col a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #087abf;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row ">
    <div class="col categories_col">
      <div class="row"><a href="#">Spirits &amp; Wines</a></div>
      <div class="row"><img src="images/wine.jpg"></div>
      <div class="row"><a href="#"><i class="mdfi_av_play_circle_fill"></i></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col categories_col">
      <div class="row"><a href="#">Gadgets</a></a>
      </div>
      <div class="row"><img src="images/ipod.jpg"></div>
      <div class="row"><a href="#"><i class="mdfi_av_play_circle_fill"></i></a></div>
    </div>

    <div class="col categories_col">
      <div class="row"><a href="#">Outdoor &amp; Living</a></div>
      <div class="row"><img src="images/tent.jpg"></div>
      <div class="row"><a href="#"><i class="mdfi_av_play_circle_fill"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col categories_col">
      <div class="row"><a href="#">Flowers &amp; Hampers</a></div>
      <div class="row"><img src="images/beauty.jpg"></div>
      <div class="row"><a href="#"><i class="mdfi_av_play_circle_fill"></i></a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col categories_col">
      <div class="row"><a href="#">Lingerie</a></div>
      <div class="row"><img src="images/lingerie.jpg"></div>
      <div class="row"><a href="#"><i class="mdfi_av_play_circle_fill"></i></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please help me center the links with names "Spirits & Wines", "Gadgets", etc

Comment: Looks centered to me https://www.bootply.com/B41VITCLjg

Comment: try using the `text-center` native bootstrap class for this

Comment: yes, they are centered. are u sure that you are loading the css??? please, check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to rewrite the html, using a div with class 'row' for each name ("Spirits & Wines", "Gadgets") and inside create div with class col-offset or colmargin, please view [Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :
    `<div class="container">`
        `<div class="row " >`
            `<div class="col-md-12" style='text-align:center'>`
                 `<a href="#">Spirits &amp; Wines</a><br/>`
                 `<img src="images/wine.jpg"><br/>`
                 `<a href="#"><i class="mdfi_av_play_circle_fill"></i></a>`
             `</div>`
         `</div>`
     `</div>`

Answer (score 0):

I can see that all the answers everybody gave is working but for some reason, in the whole piece of code I have on my PC, it doesn't center when I give the **divs** a class of **row**. So what I did was kill the styling bootstrap options given to the **divs** when it has the name **row**. I now just called it **row1** and then my **text-align: center** worked which was called in **.categories_col**

Below is before and after:

[image]

You can see that my code editor shows that it is aligned to the left(this is with div **row**)

Below you can see after I named the divs **row1**

[image]

Thank you community for helping me with options. I wish I could mark all of them as the correct answer but in this case, what I tried by changing the div names worked the best for me.

**YOUR ANSWERS ARE STILL CORRECT FOR CENTERING WITH BOOTSTRAP**