# Centering li col-md-5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any graceful way to center a group of `.col-md-5`?

I have a ul and in the ul I have a list of li's that stack next to each other in two columns. I need to center this ul, but everything I come up with either doesn't work or is ugly.

My code is below.

```html
<div class="container">
                
                    <ul class="row">
                    
                    
                    <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li><li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li><li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
                      <li class="col-md-5">
                        <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
                        <span>Name</span>
                    </li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

and an example below.

https://www.bootply.com/HBsEFFrrGw

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Center a column using Twitter Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18153234/center-a-column-using-twitter-bootstrap-3)

Comment: @Rob it's bootstrap4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `justify-content-center` class on your row

```html
<div class="container">

  <ul class="row justify-content-center">
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>
    <li class="col-md-5">
      <span class="circle alert-primary">3</span>
      <span>Name</span>
    </li>




  </ul>
</div>


<div id="push"></div>
```

[Updated Bootply](https://www.bootply.com/jH5Vk4Qa9V)

Comment: Thank you. I've never heard of that class before!

Answer (score 1):

Use .col-md-6 and replace margin by padding with warp div
and modify css

```
li > div{
 border:1px solid lightgray;
 padding:1em
}
```

example
https://www.bootply.com/S1vwo3AfdO

Answer (score 0):

You could do an `nth-child()` selector, something like this;

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  li.col-md-5:nth-child(odd) {
    margin-left: 8.333333%; // set to whatever you need to center them
  }
}
```

OR add `justify-content-center` class to the row and let bootstrap handle the rest - note this will center the last item as well which may not be the desired outcome