# Center align of 2 images using Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to align 2 images which are responsive in the center of the page.

I am using the .container class but still it is towards right.

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: There are many questions similar to what you are asking for. Have a look at [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032609/center-align-a-column-in-twitter-bootstrap) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

container class in bootstrap provides margin-left:% and margin-right-% so page looks beautiful,you need to use fluid-grid system to make it responsive 
For eg ,

```
  `<div class="container">
    <div class="col-sm-12 ">
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img  style="text-align:center" src=""/></div>
        <div class="col-sm-6"><img style="text-align:center" src=""/></div>
    </div>
   </div>`
```