# Vertical Center align a column in Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, vertical-alignment

I tried a dozen ways to center align column vertically in bootstrap but none worked.
My problem is I don't know then height of column.
Can I use flexbox? Is it embedded in Bootstrap 3?
    [image: items are not vertically centered]

my code :

```
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-sm-12">

    <div class="col-md-2" style="padding: 0px">
      <img alt="img" src="image/avatar/unknown.png" class="img-responsive forum-avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6">
      <span class="qap-q-author">user1</span>
      <br>
      <span class="qap-q-h">test</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <span class="text-muted pull-right qap-a-cnt">
        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="badge">1</span>
      </span>
      <span class="qap-q-h pull-right">1</span>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-2">
      <i class="fa fa-group" style="font-size: 32px"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your sample code here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flexbox can be used but then you will have to take care of old browsers. Center aligning a column in bootstrap is explained here perfectly. Have a look [center align column in bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18032609/center-align-a-column-in-twitter-bootstrap)

You can center align the columns by using flexbox.

you can add this class to parent container of your div which you want to center align:

```
.v-center {
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
}
```

Read more about vertically aligning columns here: [vertical align columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547819/vertical-align-with-bootstrap-3)

Comment: I have updated my answer for vertical alignment also.